# Criteria for when elements generate an ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a smooth algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$.  Let $I$ be an ideal of $A$, and suppose that $I/I^2$ is a free $R:=A/I$ module.  Suppose further that there exists elements $f_1,\dots,f_n\in I$ such that the natural map
$$
R\otimes_{k}\langle f_1,\dots,f_n\rangle\to I/I^2
$$
is an isomorphism; in other words the images of $f_1,\dots,f_n$ in $I/I^2$ trivialize it over $R$.

Then is it true that $(f_1,\dots,f_n)=I$?  In other words, must $f_1,\dots,f_n$ generate the ideal $I$?

Answer (score 0):

I think I realized the answer is no, with a counterexample being the twisted cubic, as always.

Namely, consider the subvariety $Y$ of $\mathbb{A}^3$ cut out the equations $x-y^2,xw-y,yw-1$.  If we take the first two equations, their differentials are linearly independent along $Y$, but they do not cut out all of $Y$.

Please let me know if this is correct though!

Comment: Here is a simple example. Take $I=(xy-1)\subset k[x,y]$. Then, $x(xy-1)$ generates the free $k[x,y]/I$ module $I/I^2$, but does not generate $I$. A more interesting, but open question is, given $I$ an ideal of a polynomial ring $R$ over a field and $I/I^2$ is a free module of rank $r$ over $R/I$, can $I$ be generated by $r$ elements?

Comment: Thanks!  Wait why doesn't the twisted cubic example given above provide a counterexample to your question?  It seems there the conormal module $I/I^2$ is free of rank 2, with generators say $x-y^2$ and $xw-y$?

Comment: The twisted cubic is in fact generated by 2 equations. The second and third equations will suffice. I am not asking for taking elements in $I$ which generate $I/I^2$ and asking whether they generate $I$, which my trivial example says is false. For codimension one (trivially) and codimension 2, the question has an affirmative answer, thanks to a construction of Serre and Quillen-Suslin Theorem.

Comment: Ah gotcha okay!